# Keyboard accessibility in react-widgets combobox

Tags: combobox, accessibility, react-widgets

I'm using the React Widgets Combobox with Group Headings and I can't get keyboard navigation to work.

The first example on the documentation page has a keyboard accessible dropdown (up / down arrow keys) but I can't see the source code for it, and it doesn't use group headings:

https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/Combobox/

The later examples on that page which show source code are not keyboard accessible.

I've searched but not found any example code showing how to enable keyboard accessibility on a react widgets Combobox.

Here's my code:

```
const GroupHeading = ({ item }) => {
    switch (item) {
        case 'group 1':
            return <span>Group 1</span>;

        case 'group 2':
            return <span>Group 2</span>;

        default:
            return null;
    }
};

const ComboboxItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <span className="combobox-dropdown">
            <span className="item">{item.name}</span>
        </span>
    );

<Combobox
    name={widgetId}
    id={widgetId}
    data={data}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    minLength={2}
    filter="contains"
    groupComponent={GroupHeading}
    groupBy={item => item.type}
    valueField="id"
    textField="name"
    itemComponent={ComboboxItem}
    placeholder="Enter search text"
    onChange={param => onChange(param, widgetId)}
    onSelect={param => onSelect(param, widgetId)}
    inputProps={inputProps}
    autoFocus
/>
```

Can anybody say how to allow users to select dropdown items with the keyboard? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Two of the option objects in my data array had the same id, by mistake. Keyboard navigation must work by checking valueField and this will have to be unique.

The sort of thing that seems obvious in hindsight, but can be easy to miss when something is new to you.